# Convert UTC time to local time with specific format in Redshift

Tags: timezone, redshift

I have a column called `created_at` with data stored in UTC without timezone like : `2017-02-05 15:43:27.151`

I would like to convert to an other timezone like CET in specific format like :

`2017-02-08 16:43:27 +01:00`

I succeed converting the time to specific timezone but needed to specify the timezone of the input. Query looks like :

```
SELECT created_at, 
       (created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'CET' AS cet 
FROM my_table;

[
  {
    "created_at" : "2017-02-08 15:43:27.151",
    "cet"        : "2017-02-08 16:43:27.151"
  }
]
```

But I failed to extract or generate from timezone code the timezone offset.

I tried

```
SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_HOUR
               FROM
                 (SELECT '2017-02-08 15:43:27.151' AT TIME ZONE 'CET'));
[
  {
    "date_part" : 0
  }
]
```

How to get the `2017-02-08 16:43:27 +01:00` ?

**EDIT 1**:

```
SHOW timezone; --utc
SELECT current_timestamp; -- 2017-02-09 11:00:20.225039+00
SELECT to_char(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CET', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS OF'); -- 2017-02-09 12:00:35 +00
```

Why the offset is 00? (I'm using `OF` because I'm on Redshift)?

> OF |  Offset from UTC; valid for TIMESTAMPTZ only

From [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html)

**EDIT 2**: I thought `AT TIME ZONE 'CET'` turn the the date to timestamptz but I was wrong. You need to cast the date as `::timestamptz` then `OF` will display the UTC offset.

```
SELECT to_char((current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CET')::timestamptz, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS OF'); 
--2017-02-09 14:48:48 +01
```

Now I need to add the `:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching into the Redshift documentation :

I finally did :

```
SELECT to_char((current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'CET')::timestamptz, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS OF') || ':00' AS created_at
-- 2017-02-09 15:10:15 +01:00
```

Timestamp need to be converted into the expected time zone `AT TIME ZONE ...` then casted with a time zone otherwise `OF` will not display the UTC offset.

I add `:00` after verifying time zones can't display time zones with minutes :

```
SELECT pg_timezone_names();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '2017-02-08 15:43:27.151' AT TIME ZONE 'CET' - '2017-02-08 15:43:27.151' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Comment: More the opposite no? `SELECT '2017-02-08 15:43:27.151' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - '2017-02-08 15:43:27.151' AT TIME ZONE 'CET';`

Comment: Question is about +01:00 as answer. Result of your query is -01:00

Comment: Hmm. I have this `SHOW timezone; -- 'utc'
SELECT '2017-02-08 15:43:27.151' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - '2017-02-08 15:43:27.151' AT TIME ZONE 'CET'; -- '01:00:00'`

Comment: CET - is Central European Time. It is + 1 hour to UTC.